# Targeting identical classes in different packages

Tags: java, oop, package, api-design

I have created a library which supports an application, however in the newest version of the application the developer has changed the structure without changing the class names.

So version 1 of the application has classX in package A but version 2 has classX in package B. How can I develop my library in a way which allows supporting both of these in the same build?

Edit: My library is dependent on the application, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** You can't.

**Real answer:** *Your library should be able to exist independently of any application that uses it.* The purpose of a library is to provide a set of reusable, modular code that you can use in any application. If your library is directly dependent on application classes, then it seems like a redesign should be seriously considered, as your dependencies are backwards. For example, have `A.classX` and `B.classX` both implement some interface (or extend some class) that your library provides, then have the *application* pass instances of those objects, or `Class`'s for those objects, *to* the library.

If your "library" can't be designed this way then consider integrating it into application code, making it a direct part of the application, and come up with a better team workflow for you, the other developer, and others to work on the same project together.

**Quick fix answer:** Do not provide backward compatibility, as Jigar Joshi states in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22723515/616460).

**Bad answer:** You could hack a fragile solution together with reflection if you really had to. But please note that the "real answer" is going to last in the long run. You are already seeing the issues with the design you have currently chosen (hence your question), and a reflection based solution isn't going to prevent that from happening again (or even be reliable).

Comment: I don't think library is dependent on app, it is otherways and OP wants to take care of compatibility

Comment: @JigarJoshi Hm; maybe I misinterpreted, but I read it as the *application* has `B.classX` (which used to be `A.classX`) and the library is now broken because the library directly referenced the application's `A.classX`. This seems like a very strange scenario.

Comment: @JasonC has this the correct way around, sorry if I expressed this poorly

Comment: @user3474299 If the application developer is not willing to work with you, and if backward compatibility is not critical, I suggest Jigar Joshi's answer -- just change your library to use `B` and users will have to update the application. Is there a compelling reason to maintain backward compatibility here; will it be an issue for users to upgrade (beyond inconvenience, which is the cost of what seems like poor support from the application developer from your library here)?

Answer (score 1):

That is a *bad* decision, if you still want to make it work you need to provide skeleton classes with old structure and delegate calls to new version of class but it would get very *dirty*

better to *not* provide backward compatibility if you are firm with the renaming decision

Comment: The main problem is that the application is not in my control what so ever, it is developed by a third party unrelated to myself.

Comment: @user3474299 So the application doesn't *use* your library, your library just controls some third-party application?

Comment: but API is so do not rename package, if really really required then declare about compatibility in release note

Comment: Is the application developer actually aware of your library's existence?

Comment: My library provides extended functionality for a closed source program , I am using a decompiler and aspect-orientation to access hidden methods within the application. 
The developer is aware of my library as they asked me to create it, however since then they have changed the structure of the program. There is 0% chance of the application being changed.

Comment: sounds like you can't change app code, and you can't change library code back to good, then dirty hack is the way to go as stated in answer

Comment: @user3474299 You could perhaps leave the old version of your library around for a limited amount of time to provide a convenience to users who have not updated the application yet; e.g. freeze the previous version of the library and leave it available for, say, 2 months (and notify users ahead of time that the old version is being phased out, and bugfixes, new features, etc. require the new version).